# Catching Errors while working with Excel in Interop

Tags: c#, excel, vba, outlook, office-interop

if I would want to catch any Error that could occur while automatizing Excel by C#-Interop, what would be the best way to achieve this?

I've created a thread that retrieves all Child-Window Window-Handles to check if a VBA-Error popped up, but I can't believe this is the kings-way.

The rest get's afaik already piped to C# but I need to know REALLY everything that is going on. Maybe you've got some better Ideas, thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Code Sample:

```
     <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function EnumChildWindows(ByVal hWndParent As System.IntPtr, ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumWindowsProc, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
Private Delegate Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowText")>
Public Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function EnumWindows(ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumWindowsProc, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, <Out()> ByVal lParam As StringBuilder) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetClassName(ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr, _
ByVal lpClassName As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
    ' Leave function empty    
End Function

Public Function HandleAccess()
    While (True)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Try
            myApplication.hWndAccessApp()
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(myApplication.hWndAccessApp(), my_proc_id)
            If (my_proc_id <> 0) Then
                my_hwnd = myApplication.hWndAccessApp
                EnumWindows(New EnumWindowsProc(AddressOf isMacroError), 0)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString())
            If alreadyLaunched = True Then
                Return False
            End If
        End Try
    End While
    Return True
End Function

Public Function isMacroError(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr)
    Dim form_to_work_with As Access.Form
    Dim check_for_proc_id As Integer
    Dim anzahl_daten As Integer

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, check_for_proc_id)
    If check_for_proc_id = my_proc_id Then
        Dim capacity As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd)
        If capacity > 0 Then
            Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(capacity + 1)
            GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, capacity + 1)
            If (determineControlType(hWnd, 0).Equals("OFormPopupNC")) Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To myApplication.Forms.Count - 1
                    If myApplication.Forms.Item(i).Name.Equals("Testform") Or myApplication.Forms.Item(i).Name.Equals("TestForm") Then
                        form_to_work_with = myApplication.Forms.Item(i)
                        Dim CalendarWeek As Access.ComboBox = DirectCast(form_to_work_with.Controls("auswahl"), Access.ComboBox)
                        Dim AnzahlDaten As HashSet(Of Access.TextBox) = New HashSet(Of Access.TextBox)
                        Dim AnzahlDaten_after As HashSet(Of Access.TextBox) = New HashSet(Of Access.TextBox)
                        For Each control In form_to_work_with.Controls
                            If control.ToString().Equals("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.TextBoxClass") Then
                                AnzahlDaten.Add(DirectCast(control, Access.TextBox))
                                AnzahlDaten_after.Add(DirectCast(control, Access.TextBox))
                            End If
                        Next
                        If AnzahlDaten.Count > 0 Then
                            For Each textbox As Access.TextBox In AnzahlDaten
                                If textbox.Name.StartsWith("Anzahl") Or textbox.Name.StartsWith("Daten") Then
                                Else
                                    AnzahlDaten_after.Remove(textbox)
                                End If
                            Next
                            AnzahlDaten = AnzahlDaten_after
                            For Each textbox As Access.TextBox In AnzahlDaten
                                Integer.TryParse(textbox.Value.ToString, anzahl_daten)
                                If anzahl_daten = 0 Then
                                End If
                            Next
                            myApplication.DoCmd.RunMacro("TestForm.btn_x_Click")
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            ElseIf (sb.ToString().Equals("Microsoft Visual Basic")) Then
                EnumChildWindows(hWnd, New EnumWindowsProc(AddressOf checkForChilds), 0)
                Debug.Print("Makro Fehler!")
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Public Function checkForChilds(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr)
    Dim capacity As Integer = (SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, New StringBuilder) + 1)
    If capacity > 1 Then
        Dim temp_string_builder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(capacity)
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, capacity, temp_string_builder)
        Debug.Print(temp_string_builder.ToString)
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Public Function determineControlType(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As String
    Dim temp_string_builder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(256)
    Dim nRet As Integer = GetClassName(hWnd, temp_string_builder, 256)
    If (nRet <> 0) Then
        Return temp_string_builder.ToString
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

This is what my current state lookslike, I'm a bit further because there is another construction in the project (and this here is VB.NET) but all in all this (tries to) catch Exceptions-Thrown in seperate Windows.

Comment: please read how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hello Macro Man, yes I know that rules of StackOverflow say a example should provided. If you want me to, I can paste what I wrote down in code, but mainly I'm looking for Ideas how to approach the problem, nobody should write what I have to, but just to grasp an encounter to that problem.

Comment: `I'm looking for Ideas how to approach the problem` that is too broad for a question on here, the idea is that you have a specific programming problem that can be replicated with a code sample. It's not for "best practice" questions which is what you are asking for.

Comment: Added the sample which was Introduced in main thread, sorry for misbehavoiur =<

Comment: So now you've got a C# project that's using VBA, but the code is in VB.NET???

Comment: Old code :=) For another Project which never finished up. The new replaces it in its whole but it's written in C#. This functionality is missing yet, but I would totally do the conversion if the effort is worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit further on this occasion, especially for Macro-Errors UI-Automation seems like the way to go. I put an event handler on the Access-Window and it keeps spitting out Windows that pop up as children of it. Now another problem occurred, this only works when the Application is set as Visible, which is not as nice as it would be hidden until an unwanted exception has got along. I don't get why it does it, maybe it's a protection mechanism included by MS?

If somebody got any tips I'm excited, here is my current code: applyable to any other window or so else.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using Automation = System.Windows.Automation;

namespace testNS
{
public class UIAutomation
{
    private AutomationElement _currentScope = null;

    public UIAutomation(int hwnd)
    {
        if (_currentScope == null)
            _currentScope = AutomationElement.FromHandle((IntPtr)hwnd);

        Automation.Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(Automation.WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
        _currentScope, TreeScope.Subtree, this.handleWindowEvents);
    }

    public void handleWindowEvents(object src, Automation.AutomationEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            AutomationElement aeSrc = src as AutomationElement;
            if (aeSrc.Current.Name.Contains("Visual Basic"))
            {
               Int32? parentWindowHandle = (_currentScope.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NativeWindowHandleProperty) as Int32?);
                if (parentWindowHandle != null && parentWindowHandle > 0)
                {
                    IntPtr ptrHandle = (IntPtr) parentWindowHandle;
                    //NativeMethods.ShowWindow(ptrHandle, 1);
                }
                AutomationElementCollection childrenAutomationElementCollection = aeSrc.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
                foreach (AutomationElement aeChildren in childrenAutomationElementCollection)
                {
                    if (aeChildren.Current.Name.Length > 10)
                        Console.WriteLine(aeChildren.Current.Name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public void unregister()
    {
        if (_currentScope != null)
        {
            Automation.Automation.RemoveAutomationEventHandler(Automation.WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent, _currentScope, this.handleWindowEvents);
        }
    }
}
}
```